# How to bind several Scroll listener on a listview?

Tags: android, listview, listener

I would like to create a listview with Sticky Section Header and a floating action button.

I use 2 libs for this (StickyListHeaders and FloatingActionButton) but they need to bind scroll listener to the listview to works. The probleme is that there can be only one scroll listener on listview.

How could I use 2 scroll listener on a listview?

Comment: use the same instance of the listener for both

Comment: you could also implement an observer on the top of the listener

Comment: @tyczj I can't use the same instanace of listener. StickyHeader has its own listener and floatingActionButton too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Combining a list of scroll listeners and making only one listener to notify all of them is pretty straightforward solution to your request.

Note: If you plan to override methods from `OnScrollListener` from `MultiScrollListener`, make sure you make a `super` call

```
import android.widget.AbsListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by nikola on 9/12/14.
 */
public class MultiScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    List<AbsListView.OnScrollListener> mListeners = new ArrayList<AbsListView.OnScrollListener>();
    public void addScrollListener(AbsListView.OnScrollListener listener){
        mListeners.add(listener);
    }
    public void removeListener(AbsListView.OnScrollListener listener){
        mListeners.remove(listener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        for(AbsListView.OnScrollListener listener: mListeners){
            listener.onScrollStateChanged(view,scrollState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        for(AbsListView.OnScrollListener listener: mListeners){
            listener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MultiScrollListener scrolls = new MultiScrollListener();
scrolls.addScrollListener(scroll1);
scrolls.addScrollListener(scroll2);
mListView.setOnScrollListener(scrolls);
```